# Init a controller that depends on an unloaded dependency

Tags: angularjs

With `ui-router` I created a state which has one of its view that displays the current user status. The following code gets the current user status:

```
var sydney = sydney || {};
sydney.checkAuth = function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id : sydney.CLIENT_ID,
        scope : sydney.SCOPES,
        immediate : true
    }, sydney.handleAuthResult);
}

sydney.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
        // The user has authorized access
        console.log("User is signed in");
    } else {
        // User has not Authenticated and Authorized
        console.log("User is not signed in");
    }
}
```

The `state` is defined as:

```
$stateProvider
.state('route1', {
    url: "/route1",
    views : {
        "headerView" : {
            templateUrl : 'partials/header.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        },
        "navigationView" : {
            templateUrl : 'partials/navigation.html',
            controller: 'NavigationController'
        },
        "contentView": {
            templateUrl : 'partials/content1.html'
        }
    }
})
```

The `LoginController`:

```
function LoginController($scope, $state) {
    $scope.checkUserStatus = function() {
        sydney.checkAuth();
    }
}
```

I need to glue all these parts, so when the `headerView` is displayed, I can display the user status (logged in or not).

The first thing I did is to create a variable in the `LoginController` to hold the status

```
$scope.userStatus = sydney.checkAuth();
```

The issue is that `sydney.checkAuth` has a dependency on the `Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript` which is not loaded at the time when the `LoginController` is created. So I get `gapi is not defined` which totally makes sense.

Another solution is to initialize `$scope.userStatus` after `gapi` is loaded (in the callback). But how do you tell the controller to update `$scope.userStatus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few different approaches to this kind of issue.

In a similar situation I have had success injecting `$rootScope` using `$broadcast` to send an event from the dependency, i.e. `gapiSetup` - this can then be picked up as required in your controllers, services etc.

Specifically, using `$broadcast` decouples the components, and also allows you to use that event in multiple places - as in if you would need to update other places than just your header.